# ColorBox onClick run JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using ColorBox inline functionality and I have created a button which I've set to close the window when clicked:

```
$('.closebutton').live('click', function(){
        $.fn.colorbox.close();
    });
```

I have another function which I want to run when the button is clicked, so I've used:

```
<button class="closebutton" onclick="myFunction();">Close</button>
```

Problem is the myFunction is not working above.

Any ideas please?

UPDATE:

Here is where the code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"}); //for colorbox inline
    $('#cboxClose').remove(); //remove popup window close button

    $('.closebutton').live('click', function(){
        $.fn.colorbox.close();
        myFunction();
    });
```

Adding `myFunction();` before or after `$.fn.colorbox.close();` is not working

myFunction code: (This goes after the code above on the page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    $("#ajax-form").submit(function(){
        $.post("update.php",
        $("#ajax-form").serialize(),
            function(data){
                $('#jqm').attr('src', 
                $('#jqm').attr('src'));
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
}
</script>
```

UPDATE 2:

I'll try to explain better: I have a form and input on the main page that works find, so when you add some text to the input box and submit then form then the value of the input is submitted.
Now, when I put that same input in the inline area of colorBox so that it appears inside the popup window the value is not submitted. I've tried grabbing JS errors on firebag but cannot see anything there.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Where is myFunction() defined? Could you please add that code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add `myFunction()` before `$.fn.colorbox.close();`? That way you can be sure what order things are handled in.

Comment: Do you have a link to it not working? Or can you provide the code for `myFunction()`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using inline javascript, you could simply do something like this :

```
$('.closebutton').live('click', function(){
    $.fn.colorbox.close();
    myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Do you get into `myFunction` and the code there doesn't execute right or is the function not even called?

Comment: The code there doesn't execute right. When the function is called from inside the inline popup the myFunction code is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that `myFunction()` (the onClick attribute) is being overridden by jQuery. If you want your function to execute whenever a `.closebutton` is clicked just use:

```
$('.closebutton').live('click', function(){
        $.fn.colorbox.close();
        myFunction();
});
```

If its only for that button, try adding an id to that button and:

```
$('.closebutton').live('click', function(){
   $.fn.colorbox.close();
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'exampleID')){
      myFunction();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, after reading your update #2, I understand that actually your problem is not that the myFunction code doesn't execute right.

The problem is that you moved your input inside the colorbox, so its value doesn't submit with the form, wich is normal because the input is now *outside* the form.

You could either simply move your whole form inside the colorbox, or use javascript to copy the value of the input you moved outside of your form in a hidden input.